# Apache/php running on Windows require & include not working

Tags: php, apache

I have a problem getting include or require to work with apache running on windows. The index.php in the root folder works fine but the index.php file in the marketing folder can find the file.

```
config/config.php
inc/header.php
index.php
/marketing/index.php
```

I have

```
<?php require_once '/config/config.php'; ?>
```

In header.php & in /marketing/index.php i have

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/header.php'); ?>
```

I haven't had this problem before so i'm really scratching my head as to why this is.

Comment: can you do this, `echo realpath('/config/config.php');` to give yourself an idea of your directory context.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between an _absolute_ path (`/config/config.php`) and a _relative_ path (`config/config.php`)...

Comment: header.php `<?php require_once(__DIR__ . '/../config/config.php'); ?>`

Comment: Thank you @Dale. That did the trick!